# Property of open neighborhood in Euclidean space.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, general-topology

Let $a\in \mathbb{R}^{2n}$, $z \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and $\epsilon >0$. There exists or not $x=(x_1,x_2) \in B_{\epsilon}(a)=\{ y \in \mathbb{R}^{2n} \mid ||y-a||<\epsilon \}$ and $\lambda \neq 0$ such that

$$x_1+x_2=\lambda z$$

My idea is using the fact that the open neighborhood $B_{\epsilon}(a)$ is diffeomorphic to the whole space $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. However, I did not success yet.

Any other answers or ideas are very welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

If $\|a\|<\varepsilon $, the function $g:B_\varepsilon (a)\times (\mathbb R\setminus \{0\})\to \mathbb R^n$ defined by $$g(x,y,\lambda ):=\frac{x+y}{\lambda },$$
is surjective. If $\|a\|\geq \varepsilon $, then $z=0$ won't be reached.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Could you give more detail on how to show that it's subjective? I think it's not true. For example, if we take $x \gg 0$ big enough, then $\frac{x+y}{\lambda} \neq 0$.

Comment: @N.Quy:  You are absolutely correct (I was thinking about $a=(0,0)$).  If $\|a\|<\varepsilon $, then it's surjective, otherwise, we have surjectivity only from $B_\varepsilon (a)\times \mathbb R^*\to \mathbb R^n\setminus \{0\}$. So, the statement is a bit ambiguous as written, but with no more information, it's indeed wrong, and $z=0$ won't be reached if $\|a\|>\varepsilon $).

Comment: Anyway, for the case $||a||<\epsilon$, how we can show that $g(x,y,\lambda)$ is surjective.

Comment: Let $z\in \mathbb R^n$. I write $a=(a_1,a_2)\in \mathbb R^{2n}$. Take $y=0$ and $x\in \{tz\mid t\in (0,1]\}\cap B_\varepsilon (a)$. In particular, $x=tz$ for some $t\in (0,1]$. Finally, take $\lambda =t$, and thus $z=g(x,0,t)$. @N.Quy